# Python flask: how to avoid users from browsing static directory

Tags: python, apache

I followed digital ocean [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) to deploy my Flask application using Apache server. Now the problem is when a user visits `mywebsite.com/static`, all the files in the static directory is available to that user. How to avoid users from browsing static directory?

My apache virtual host file looks this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mywebsite.com
        ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
        <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If your don't want the user to access the static directory, don't have one.

Comment: @Daniel: Then where to keep all css, js and image files?

Comment: Static files must be accessible to the user - do you instead want to prevent users from browsing the directory?

Comment: If you have css, js and image files, the user have to access them.

Comment: Yes, I don't want users to browse that directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent generation of directory indexes with the `Option -Indexes` directive:

```
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>
```

Alternatively, you can place the directive in an `.htaccess` file in the appropriate directory.

Comment: Where should I place this exactly?